# How to make nomenclature entries indent?

Tags: spacing, nomenclature

The nomenclature entries is left align without indent by default:

```
 \printnomenclature[2.5 cm]
```

See e.g. [image: Nom]

I want to make these symbols `indent`  from left margin for `1 ex` or `1 em`. But I have just lost in the package manual `nomenclature`.

So how can I redefine the `indent` value?

---

`nomgroup` is redefined as:

```
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
 \makenomenclature
  \renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{%
    \item[\textbf{Acronyms}] }{% A - Acronyms
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
      \item[\textbf{Roman Symbols}]}{% R - Roman
       \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
        \item[\textbf{Greek Symbols }]}{% G - Greek
         \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
          \item[\textbf{Superscripts  }]}{{% S - Superscripts
       \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{U}}{%
        \item[\textbf{Subscripts }]}{{% U - Subscripts
         \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{%
          \item[\textbf{Other Symbols }]}% X - Other Symbols
                    {{}}}}}}}}}}
```

Examples of nomenclature input:

```
\nomenclature[rV]{$V$ }{Fluid control volume}
\nomenclature[ruf]{$\bm{u}_f$ }{Fluid velocity}
\nomenclature[gepsilonf]{$\epsilon_f$ }{Fluid porosity}
\nomenclature[rfb]{$\bm{f}_b$ }{Body force per unit volume}
\nomenclature[gepsilonf]{$\epsilon_f$ }{Fluid porosity}
\nomenclature[gsigma]{$\bm{\sigma} $ }{Cauchy stress tensor}
```

Comment: Maybe `\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{\hspace{1em}#1}`? Seems to be a bit of a hack, though...

Comment: @cgnieder It did work. but the group name `Acronyms` is also indent. As I have redefined the `\nomgroup`, how do I only make the symbols indent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Patch `\thenomenclature` to do also `\itemindent 1em`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
  {\leftmargin\labelwidth}
  {\leftmargin\labelwidth\itemindent 1em }
  {}{}

\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
a\nomenclature{ALE}{Arbitrary Lagrangian-Eulerian Method}
b\nomenclature{AOR}{Angle of repose}
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since your group labels are typeset with `\item`, then you have also to change them so they skip back by the current `\itemindent`:

```
\newcommand{\nomenclheader}[1]{\item[\hspace*{-\itemindent}#1]}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{%
   \nomenclheader{\textbf{Acronyms}}}{%                   A - Acronyms
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
     \nomenclheader{\textbf{Roman Symbols}}}{%            R - Roman
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
        \nomenclheader{\textbf{Greek Symbols}}}{%          G - Greek
          \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
           \nomenclheader{\textbf{Superscripts}}}{{%      S - Superscripts
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{U}}{%
         \nomenclheader{\textbf{Subscripts}}}{{%           U - Subscripts
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{%
         \nomenclheader{\textbf{Other Symbols}}}%          X - Other Symbols
                       {{}}}}}}}}}}
```

You'll probably have less problem in maintaining the code above if you say

```
\usepackage{xstring}
```

and then

```
\newcommand{\nomenclheader}[1]{%
  \item[\hspace*{-\itemindent}\normalfont\bfseries #1]}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
   {A}{\nomenclheader{Acronyms}}%      A - Acronyms
   {R}{\nomenclheader{Roman Symbols}}% R - Roman
   {G}{\nomenclheader{Greek Symbols}}% G - Greek
   {S}{\nomenclheader{Superscripts}}%  S - Superscripts
   {U}{\nomenclheader{Subscripts}}%    U - Subscripts
   {X}{\nomenclheader{Other Symbols}}% X - Other Symbols
  }%
}
```

---

### Complete example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
  {\leftmargin\labelwidth}
  {\leftmargin\labelwidth\itemindent 1em }
  {}{}

\newcommand{\nomenclheader}[1]{%
  \item[\hspace*{-\itemindent}\normalfont\bfseries#1]}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
   {A}{\nomenclheader{Acronyms}}%      A - Acronyms
   {R}{\nomenclheader{Roman Symbols}}% R - Roman
   {G}{\nomenclheader{Greek Symbols}}% G - Greek
   {S}{\nomenclheader{Superscripts}}%  S - Superscripts
   {U}{\nomenclheader{Subscripts}}%    U - Subscripts
   {X}{\nomenclheader{Other Symbols}}% X - Other Symbols
  }%
}

\begin{document}
Some text for getting output.

\nomenclature[rV]{$V$}{Fluid control volume}
\nomenclature[ruf]{$\bm{u}_f$}{Fluid velocity}
\nomenclature[gepsilonf]{$\epsilon_f$}{Fluid porosity}
\nomenclature[rfb]{$\bm{f}_b$}{Body force per unit volume}
\nomenclature[gepsilonf]{$\epsilon_f$}{Fluid porosity}
\nomenclature[gsigma]{$\bm{\sigma}$}{Cauchy stress tensor}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The command `\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{\hspace{1em}#1}` does work. But What I want to do is to keep `Symbol group-name`, e.g. `Acronyms` shown in the above figure not indent.

Comment: @KOF Please, make a new question with a *complete* compilable example that shows the problem. Note that this question has nothing like a complete compilable example.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have spacing corrected:
    `\usepackage{nomencl}`
    `\makenomenclature`
    `\setlength\nomlabelwidth{2cm} % your value that aligns items`